# How to pass array of images through Adapter to a NewActivity

Tags: java, xml, android-recyclerview, adapter

I want to pass images in the asset/drawable folder through adapter and then show them in a new activity. I have tried making research for guidance but didn't get what i want. I want to pass images as i pass texts from string-array to new activity.

**This is my Adapter**

```js
public class MyAdapter1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder1> implements Filterable {

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<Model1> models1, filterList1;  // this array list create a list of array which parameter define in our class
    CustomFilter1 filter1;


    public MyAdapter1(Context context, ArrayList<Model1> models) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.models1 = models;
        this.filterList1 = models;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyHolder1 onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row1, null); //this line inflate our row


        return new MyHolder1(view); //this will return our view to holder class
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyHolder1 myHolder, int i) {

        myHolder.mTitle.setText(models1.get(i).getTitle()); //here is position
        myHolder.mDesc.setText(models1.get(i).getDesc());
        myHolder.mImageView.setImageResource(models1.get(i).getIcon()); // here we used imge resource

        myHolder.setItemCLickListener(new ItemClickListener1() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClickListener(View v, int position) {

                String gTitle = models1.get(position).getTitle();
                String gDesc = models1.get(position).getDesc();
                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)myHolder.mImageView.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();

                //get our data with intent
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NewActivity2.class);
                intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle1", models1.get(position).getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("brandNewDesc1", models1.get(position).getBrandNewDesc());
                intent.putExtra("soundfile", models1.get(position).getSoundfile());
                intent.putExtra("iImage", bytes);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
                return;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return models1.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        if (filter1 == null){
            filter1 = new CustomFilter1(filterList1, this);
        }

        return filter1;
    }
}
```

**This is the Model Class**

```js
public class Model1 {

    String title;
    String desc;
    int icon;
    int soundfile;
    String brandNewDesc;

    //constructor
    public Model1(String title, String desc, String description, int icon, int music) {
        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.soundfile = music;
        this.brandNewDesc = description;
    }

    //getters


    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public String getBrandNewDesc() {

        return brandNewDesc;
    }

    public int getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public int getSoundfile() {
        return soundfile;
    }

}
```

**This is my NewActivity2 where i want to show images**

```js
private static final String URL="file:///android_asset/html_files/chant2.pdf";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new2);


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        //Keeps android screen on while reading through
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImPage1);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.c1_1));



        //get data from previous activity when item of activity is clicked using intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String mActionBarTitle = intent.getStringExtra("actionBarTitle");

        //setctionBar Title
        actionBar.setTitle(mActionBarTitle);

        //ok we are done, lets run the project
```

**The NewActivity2 XML**

```html
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroller"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImPage1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/page1_1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImPage2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/ImPage1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/page1_2" />

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImPage3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/ImPage2"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/page1_3" />

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImPage4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/ImPage3"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/page1_4" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: A good architecture with separation of concerns will automatically solve these problems for you. I suggest you read about clean architecture and SOLID principles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on how do you want to pass the array.
If you want pass the list of arrays when clicking on any of the adapter images you can write an onclicklistener for each item.
Code here.
If you want to pass in the form of a button click also use the same inside the button click listener.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NewActivity2 .class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("VAR1", models1);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

And when you reach the Activity2 in the onCreate method Use the below code snippet

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<Model1> arraylist = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("VAR1");
```

Now you will have all the list of Model1 objects. So you can load the images like you did in the adapter class.

You can also get a detailed explanation in this video : https://youtu.be/OMCctaE66b8

Hope that answered your question.